# Google Nexus 7: picture width greater than screen width

Tags: android, nexus-7

Google Nexus 7 is a 800x1280 px tablet (not counting the system 75/64 px bars height).
But when i take a picture with a camera app, the resulting pic dimensions are 960x1280.
There is no magnification set in the camera preferences.

Wondering what gives. If i have to render this picture on the screen and i scale it and maintain the aspect ratio, won't it clip some information from the original height?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you expect the resolution of the picture you take to be the same as the screen. When you take a picture with a regular digital camera you don't expect it to match up with it's screen right? The screens on most digital cameras are pretty low resolution.

So yes, if your picture and screen are different aspect ratios, then if you scale it up either you will clip areas or have empty bars on the side.

Comment: You are right. Since the device height matched the pic height resolution, that threw my thinking off. Thx for putting me back on track @kabuko